# How to start mp3info-gtk

Tags: music, gtk

I'm using the gui version of mp3info called mp3info-gtk. It installed successfully on my system but there is no icon in applications and the terminal says command not found. How do I start it? The documentation doesn't have anything that I can find in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in [`/usr/share/doc/mp3info-gtk/README.gz`](http://www.fifi.org/doc/mp3info-gtk/README):

```
Usage: GTK Version  
==================  

gmp3info [song.mp3]
```

So `gmp3info` is the command you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: you would think that might be an important thing to put in the documentation on the site huh...